# Is width=device-width redundant alongside initial-scale=1?

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

Researching viewport behaviour, I've hit a bit of a snag in understanding the meta viewport declaration.

I see `width=device-width` and `initial-scale=1` used together a lot but, as far as I can tell, the latter implies the former.

MDN also mentions that defining both a `width` and `initial-scale=1` will result in the width acting as a minimum viewport width. If this is the case then is there any need to define the width as `device-width`? Surely the initial-scale can't be 1 with any layout viewport smaller than the device-width anyway.

Am I missing something or is defining the width as device-width redundant here?

Thanks

Comment: All browsers I use imply a reduced device width when you indicate initial-scale=1 but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using both `width=device-width` and `initial-scale=1` ensure cross browser/device compatibility. For example, for iOS devices, `initial-scale=1` is needed for your page to pick up on orientation change of the device as `width=device-width` will not. Using both ensure maximum effectiveness using the meta viewport tag.

Comment: Could you give any example of the `width=device-width` changing the behaviour when `initial-scale=1` is there? Or is this more of a 'just in case' thing?

Comment: Not a just in case thing although with so many new devices always coming on the market it doesn't hurt. This page is probably what you are looking for: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/notes.html

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. That resource clarifies a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The 2 tags are not the same.

The '`width=device`' tag tells the browser to use the device's real width as the 100% width of the screen. If you omit it, a mobile device will simulate as if it has higher resolution and your content will not be stretched to full width.

The `initial-scale`  is the zoom level on first load. If it is set to 1, along with '`width=device`', then the content will not be zoomed out or in. You will also not be able to zoom out more than the initial scale (but you will still be able to zoom in). That will be as if you set 'minimum-scale' to 1 as well.

There is also a '`maximum-scale`' and if you set it to 1 as well, the user will not be able to zoom in more than the initial scale.

This is an example of how you can create an 'app-like' feeling, where the content uses the device's width in a 1:1 ratio.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm aware the tags aren't the same. What I was getting at is that the `initial-scale=1` on it's own seems to do the job of both. Just wanted to know if there is any way this could not be the case.

Comment: You asked if the latter implies the former and my answer is no it does not. Definitely did not mean to come at you as if you do not know that they are not exactly the same. Initial-scale does not tell the browser what is the actual width so, while in some browser it may work by itself, AFAIK it will not be a cross-browser solution.